# Rust basic while loop

Tags: rust

(Hopefully) A simple question from a complete rust beginner. What's wrong with my loop?

`num` evaluates to '69' rather quickly, but the loop never exits once `num` is set to '69'. I'm missing something obvious I'm sure...

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let funny_number: u16 = 69;
    let mut num: u16 = 0;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    while num != funny_number {
        let mut num: u16 = rng.gen_range(0, 100);
        println!("{}", num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new variable inside while loop which has a different scope and the num in while condition never changes. Due to which it goes into an infinite loop. Try with the below code:

```rust
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let funny_number: u16 = 69;
    let mut num: u16 = 0;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    while num != funny_number {
        num = rng.gen_range(0, 100);
        println!("{}", num);
    }
}
```